# Why doesn't my C# code produce the same output when using AES CBC 128bit encryption as this website: https://cryptii.com/pipes/aes-encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-core, aes

This is what I want to achieve using AES 128bit CBC encryption converted to hexadecimal: "30487A117196A34DE5ADCD679BA0FE71". I can achieve this when I use the website: https://cryptii.com/pipes/aes-encryption

[image: https://cryptii.com/pipes/aes-encryption]

I am however not able to achieve this using C#. Here is the code I am using:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var key = "123456789012345678901234567890af";
        var text = "raiden";
        var iv = "01C2191CFA1B33D47246E8C76EB3A824";

        var value = EncryptValues(key, iv, text);
        DecryptValues(key, iv, value);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string EncryptValues(string keyText, string ivText, string plainText)
    {
        var key = ParseBytes(keyText);
        var text = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(plainText);
        var iv = ParseBytes(ivText);

        var raw = SimpleEncrypt(new RijndaelManaged(), CipherMode.CBC, key, iv, text);

        var hexadecimalCipher = BytesToHex(raw);
        Console.WriteLine(hexadecimalCipher);
        return hexadecimalCipher.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    }

    public static void DecryptValues(string keyText, string ivText, string cipherText)
    {
        var key = ParseBytes(keyText);
        var text = ParseBytes(cipherText);
        //var expectedText = ParseBytes("30487A117196A34DE5ADCD679BA0FE71"); // <<<<< this is the expected value
        var iv = ParseBytes(ivText);

        var dec = SimpleDecrypt(new RijndaelManaged(), CipherMode.CBC, key, iv, text);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dec));
    }
    public static byte[] ParseBytes(string strToParse, bool removeSeparator = false, string separator = " ")
    {
        // Basic check
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strToParse))
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        // Check from separator
        if (removeSeparator)
            strToParse = strToParse.Replace(separator, string.Empty);

        // Parse
        var bytes = new List<byte>();
        var counter = 0;
        var characterArray = strToParse.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < strToParse.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            string byteString = $"{characterArray[counter]}{characterArray[counter + 1]}";
            var byteToAdd = byte.Parse(byteString, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            bytes.Add(byteToAdd);
            counter += 2;
        }

        return bytes.ToArray();
    }

    public static byte[] HexToBytes(string str, string separator = " ")
    {
        if (str == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (separator == null)
        {
            separator = string.Empty;
        }

        if (str == string.Empty)
        {
            return new byte[0];
        }

        int stride = 2 + separator.Length;

        if ((str.Length + separator.Length) % stride != 0)
        {
            throw new FormatException();
        }

        var bytes = new byte[(str.Length + separator.Length) / stride];

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < str.Length; i += stride)
        {
            bytes[j] = byte.Parse(str.Substring(i, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            j++;

            // There is no separator at the end!
            if (j != bytes.Length && separator != string.Empty)
            {
                if (string.CompareOrdinal(str, i + 2, separator, 0, separator.Length) != 0)
                {
                    throw new FormatException();
                }
            }
        }

        return bytes;
    }

    public static string BytesToHex(byte[] bytes, string separator = " ")
    {
        if (bytes == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (separator == null)
        {
            separator = string.Empty;
        }

        if (bytes.Length == 0)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder((bytes.Length * (2 + separator.Length)) - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i != 0)
            {
                sb.Append(separator);
            }

            sb.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static byte[] SimpleEncrypt(SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm, CipherMode cipherMode, byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] bytes)
    {
        algorithm.Mode = cipherMode;
        algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        algorithm.Key = key;
        algorithm.IV = iv;

        using (var encryptor = algorithm.CreateEncryptor())
        {
            return encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] SimpleDecrypt(SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm, CipherMode cipherMode, byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] bytes)
    {
        algorithm.Mode = cipherMode;
        algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        algorithm.Key = key;
        algorithm.IV = iv;

        using (var encryptor = algorithm.CreateDecryptor())
        {
            return encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
```

Why doesn't the outputted encrypted string in hexadecimal match: "30487A117196A34DE5ADCD679BA0FE71" - it is outputted as: "72aa9bf0ee7d8e3db7e8c763d21371b3".

The thing that's most strange here is that both the expected value: "30487A117196A34DE5ADCD679BA0FE71" and the C# generated value: "72aa9bf0ee7d8e3db7e8c763d21371b3" decrypt correctly when fed to the decryption method returning "raiden"..

Any help on this one is greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you certain the text in the website doesn't contain an invisible character, for instance  trailing newline?

Comment: @Pac0 - Yeah, the bytes generated by the website are what I need unfortunately

Comment: Try to decrypt the encrypted result in your C# program, and inspect the bytes of the decrypted string. If you say both seem to be decrypted to the expected string, this is likely to be either an encoding difference, or an invisible character difference. (so, reassuring for your algorithm!)

Comment: Your code assumes zero-padding; are you sure the web-site uses the same padding scheme? (I cannot see the padding mode on the screenshot)

Comment: @Pac0 - Yeah its an encoding issue i think, just not sure where :/

Comment: @clausc - we have a winner!!!! Thanks so much, tried: PKCS7 and problem solved.

Comment: @clausc - can you post this as an answer and I can mark resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used PKCS7 padding for the encryption (was using Zeros)